# Python: replace existing json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to add a new entry in my dictionary but with my code below it overwrites my existing file with the initial dictionary and adds a second dictionary with my new entry. I want to just have one updated dict. My initial dictionary looks like this:
[Dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1enhE.png)

This is my code:

```
@app.route("/add_movie", methods=["POST"])
def add_movie():
    test_title = request.form["title"]
    test_year = request.form["year"]
    new_entry = {"Title": test_title,"Year": test_year,}
    with open("movie_database.json", "r+", encoding="UTF-8") as open_file:
        movie_database = json.load(open_file)
        movie_database.append(new_entry)
        json.dump(movie_database, open_file)
    return render_template("search.html")
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you used

```
with open("movie_database.json", "r+", encoding="UTF-8") as open_file:
```

instead of

```
with open("movie_database.json", "a", encoding="UTF-8") as open_file:
```

opening with "a" means append to file

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately then this error message appears: io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: then you must need a+ instead of a

Comment: Then a new error appears: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Probably because of my json file.

Comment: Be sure to remember to invoke json.loads() on the contents of the file, as opposed to the file path of that JSON:

Comment: json_file_path = "/path/to/example.json"

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as j:
     contents = json.loads(j.read())

Comment: contents = json.loads(json_file_path)